# Stored Procedure in sql for selecting columns based on input values

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to code a stored procedure in SQL that does the following

1. Takes 2 inputs (BatchType and "Column Name").
2. Searches database and gives the batchdate and the data in the column = "Column name"

Code is as give below

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[chartmilldata] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    (@BatchType nvarchar (50),
     @Data nvarchar(50))
AS
BEGIN

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT BatchDate,@Data FROM --Database-- WHERE BatchType = @BatchType 

END
```

I am trying to select column from the database based on operator input. But I am not getting the output. It would be great if someone can give me a direction.

Comment: Yes. The output is supposed to be a table with first column  'BatchDate' and second column = '@Data' .

Comment: You don't select from a database, you select from a table.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to build out your `SELECT` statement as a string then execute it using `sp_executesql`.

See this page for more info:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx

This will allow you to set your query to substitute in your column name via your variable and then execute the statement.  Be sure to sanitize your inputs though!

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to use dynamic SQL, **HOWEVER** I would not recommend this solution, I don't think there is anything I can add as to why I wouldn't recommend it that isn't explained better in Erland Sommarskog in [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html).

Nonetheless, if you **had** to do it in a stored procedure you could use something like:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[chartmilldata] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    (@BatchType nvarchar (50),
     @Data nvarchar(50))
AS
BEGIN
    -- DECLARE AND SET SQL TO EXECUTE
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT BatchDate = NULL, ' + 
                                    QUOTENAME(@Data) + N' = NULL;';

    -- CHECK COLUMN IS VALID IN THE TABLE
    IF EXISTS 
    (   SELECT 1 
        FROM sys.columns
        WHERE name = @Data 
        AND object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.YourTable', 'U')
    )
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL = 'SELECT BatchDate, ' + QUOTENAME(@Data) + 
                    ' FROM dbo.YourTable WHERE BatchType = @BatchType;';
    END

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL, N'@BatchType NVARCHAR(50)', @BatchType;

END
```

It would probably be advisable to change your input parameter `@Data` to be `NVARCHAR(128)` (or the alias `SYSNAME`) though, since this is the maximum for column names.